# how can I test android app on version 3.0 API level 11

Tags: android, testing

I've developed an android app, and the client insist that I will test and debug it on old android versions (3.0,2.3).

I've tried using the SDK emulator but I was not able to get the older version actually running.
i.e. they start (extremely slow) and crash before any thing meaning-full happened.

I was considering buying a device but where can I find devices with older android versions?

I guess I could try downloading an older android img and burn it to my device but that seems too cumbersome...

Any ideas?

Comment: With which type of error the app doesn't start in the emulator?
What's inside your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: I use older versions because they load faster than the last ones wich have heavier stuff. Downloading API 3.0 from AVD Manager worked, which steps have you done?

Comment: Android emulator definitely works on versions 3.0 and 2.3. I used it many times successfully. (its slow, but then again, android emulator always was...)

Answer (score 0):

1. For 2.3, use the x86-based system image and hardware acceleration rather than the ARM image. It's quite fast.
2. For 3.x, you may want to inform your client that as of [the latest numbers](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) Honeycomb 3.2 only makes up 0.1% of devices running Google Play and 3.0-3.1 aren't even mentioned! If they still insist, you'll have to troubleshoot the computer you're trying this on. I've had varying success running those old emulators on mac vs. windows. Try lowering the ram that the emulator requires.